# .net MAUI app craches when run on Android unplugged

Tags: maui

I am running VS 2022 Version 17.6.0 Preview 1.0. I am building a .net MAUI app and I found that I can Build and run the app on my phone as long as the phone is plugged in to my computer. However when I unplug my phone the app crashes when I tapping the icon.
I have the same issue with the Android Emulator. When I run the up on the emulator by tapping the icon the splash screen appears briefly and then the app shuts down.

My phone is an Samsung 22 with the latest OS.

Comment: what do the logs show?  Do you have any exception handling setup, or crash reporting tools installed?

Comment: Did you check the device logs, e.g. using logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Jason, ewerspej, thank you for pointing me to the right path.

I found the error. I used Use App Center Analytics, Crashlytics to diagnose why my app crashed. It was a spelling error in my .xaml file. There is a YouTube video from Gerald Versluis. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz1XLecJlXc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).