# MAUI iOS App works only iPhone is plugged to Mac and launched on VS Debugger

Tags: ios, debugging, maui, visual-studio-mac

I apologise in advance for not being able to provide any kind of information about reproducing the error. I have a .NET MAUI app that (almost :-)) perfectly works when launched by Visual Studio Debugger with the iPhone plugged via USB on Mac and doesn't even launch when the phone is unplugged. Doesn't even launch means that the splash screen is loaded and then the app exist without any kind of error or crash log.
My idea is that the issue is related to provisioning, but it's only a guess. By the way the provisioning is set with my developer profile just like in the picture. [Provisioning Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDuac.png)

Here's some more info:
OS: Ventura 13.6.1 (22G313)
Visual Studio for Mac: 17.6.5 (build 417)
.NET: 8.0 RC 2

Normally when I build and deploy an iOS App with Maui I'm able to launch it even if the phone is unplugged from the Mac. Similar apps built on the same Mac with the same SDKs and .NET versions work perfectly.

Comment: so you deploy a debug build from VS to the device and it runs OK.  Then you detach the cable and launch the **same build** on the device and it crashes?

Comment: I'm not sure it crashes: there aren't any error messages or crash report. It doesn't seem to start actually. That's why I thought about a bundle signing or provisioning issue... Uh.. iOS version is 17.0.3 on iPhone 11 Pro with Developers eatures turned on

Comment: if you are not deploying it again and are running the exact same build the profile/signing is not an issue.  You can use XCode to examine the device logs to see if it shows anything useful

Comment: No, I don't. It's the same bundle which works when phone is plugged in and doesn't when not. I'm going to check on XCode... I use it only when I have to publish the app on AppStore and sometimes I forget it exists :-(

Comment: I've watched the log. As if it was the Mona Lisa... I have no clue about the issue  :-(

Comment: How about deploying on a simulator? Or use a release build on your device?

Comment: Also, there is a similar issue on GitHub : [.net MAUI app craches when run on Android unplugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678383/net-maui-app-craches-when-run-on-android-unplugged).